# Explicitly using TextBlock in Label's Content makes ContentPresenter behave strangely

Tags: .net, wpf, templates, xaml, label

I have a custom `ControlTemplate` with double `ContentPresenter`s. The template is applied to a `Label`. When I set "*Random octopus*" (just text) as Label's Content, it works exactly as expected. When I set "*<TextBlock>Random octopus</TextBlock>*" as the Content, it doesn't work (only one ContentPresenter is visually represented). I use the following code to reproduce the behavior:

```
<Window x:Class="WeirdTextBlock.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="2,2,0,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
        <Label Grid.Row="0">
            Random octopus
        </Label>
    
        <Label Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock>Random octopus</TextBlock>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here you can see how it looks like:

[image]

I thought [when you enter just text into Content property, it gets wrapped by TextBlock](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/), so why exactly is the second Label's visual representation different from the first one? And how to make the second Label behave correctly (make it look like the first Label, but only by modifying the template)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is...

- When you set a string as Content for a `Label`, a `TextBlock` is generated for the string at each `ContentPresenter`.
- When you set a `TextBlock` directly as `Content` for a `Label`, it will end up where you have the `ContentPresenter`, but since you only have one `TextBlock`, it can only be at one place at a time.

**Update**

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Style.Resources>
        <local:TypeOfConverter x:Key="TypeOfConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="content" Grid.ZIndex="2"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="secondContent" Grid.ZIndex="1" Margin="2,2,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Border Grid.ZIndex="1">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="2" Y="2"/>
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=content, Path=Content}"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                   Path=Content,
                                                   Converter={StaticResource TypeOfConverter}}"
                                 Value="{x:Type sys:String}">
                        <Setter TargetName="secondContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**TypeOfConverter**

```
public class TypeOfConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == null) ? null : value.GetType();
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Meleak: Thanks, makes sense. But how can I achieve what I'm trying to do? I somehow need to display the Content twice (in my real project, I need to apply special effects on one ContentPresenter, and then display the original content on top of that).

Comment: @Paja: Updated my answer with a possible workaround. The Bindings will break when cloning an element this way so this may not work for you..

Comment: @Meleak: Is there any way to get a visual mirror of certain element tree? It's fine when user can't interact with the mirror, I only need visual mirror, not a complete tree duplication.

Comment: @Paja: Ok, yes that should be possible. Like Kent said, a VisualBrush should work. I'll update my answer if I can get it going

Comment: @Paja: Updated my answer again. The implementation isn't complete, the problem being the Height of the VisualBrush but hopefully you can use it to get what you're after

Comment: @Meleak: Is there any way to get the code working even when string is directly set as content?

Comment: @Paja: Did you get it working? Updated my answer with a solution that works in both cases. The different ways kept getting in each others ways so I used a trigger to get around it

Comment: @Meleak: I was able to find a different solution which didn't had to duplicate the content. Your solution worked, but there were certain artifacts that prevented me from using this code. For example, when the content had multiple dropshadow effects, it didn't worked as expected.

Comment: But VisualBrush is the way to go when someone wants to visually duplicate content. Don't know which answer to accept, Kent was the first to come with this idea, but you provided code..

Comment: @Paja: Maybe you should add your own solution as an answer and accept that one. I'd like to see it as well as I wasn't very pleased with the solution I provided either

Comment: @Meleak: Well I needed to duplicate the content to achieve certain visual effect, and I was able to achieve the same effect using completely different approach. So it doesn't really answer this question. But I will accept your answer, because I really like how you stay active with your comments and really discuss the problem. :-) Sad I can't up-vote you multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying problem here is you're attempting to place a visual (the `TextBlock`) in two different places at once. A visual can only have a single parent, so one of the content presenters "wins" and the other won't have any content.

If all you want to do is have a visual copy of the `TextBlock` then use a [`VisualBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx).